# Is it possible to send only application logs (not router logs) to a Heroku logging add-on?

Tags: heroku, logging

I have a Heroku app that has a very high volume of router logs, which aren't overly useful to me (the default response code metrics are sufficient).

However, I would like to be able to capture and search *application* logs using one of the logging add-ons (papertrail, timber.io, logentries, coralogix, logz.io – I don't really mind which one). By default those add-ons seem to capture all logs, including router logs, which mean they are prohibitively expensive for me (due to the volume).

With the Heroku CLI, you can filter just application logs with `heroku logs -t --source app`. Are there any add-ons that all you to apply such a filter before ingestion, so you only get charged for what you need?

Answer (score 2):

*disclaimer: I am one of the co-founders of [Coralogix](https://www.coralogix.com).*

We believe you shouldn't pay for logs which do not interest you. This is why we developed several features to help you remove unneeded logs which clutter your environment and cost you money:

1. [Regex-based block rules](https://coralogix.com/tutorials/log-parsing-rules/) - block logs which match a certain regex pattern (or only allow logs matching a regex pattern):
   [image: Regex Block Rule]
2. [Quota optimizer](https://coralogix.com/tutorials/quota-optimizer/) - lets you block logs based on component and severity. For example, in case you are not interested in low-level logs, you can choose to block Debug on one app and Debug and Info on another app:
   [image: Coralogix Quota Optimizer]
3. [Loggregation](https://coralogix.com/tutorials/what-is-coralogix-loggregation/) - our algorithms automatically recognize which logs belong to the same log-template, clustering all log prototypes in a single view. You can find logs occurring more times than expected, taking up too much of your quota related to the value you get from them. With Loggregation you can easily spot them and block them using a block rule; e.g. the Debug log on the top of the list takes almost 80% of the package!
   [image: Coralogix Loggregation]

Of course, there are many more features in the product which make it stand out in log analytics in general, and specifically for Heroku with pre-defined Heroku alerts and [Kibana dashboard](https://coralogix.com/tutorials/predefined-heroku-visualizations/)), but the features I've described above are the things that can help your specific question.

Hope this helps :)